# wordpress echo variable that holds string from user input

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables, echo

So i'm making a plugin that makes use of the custom fields.

Now i have the fields saving and everything works fine except the final part, i cannot get echo to display the string of words as html in the head. everything displays correctly except $keywords is blank.

I have tried using global and static variables but the same result.

```
function PrintKeywords( $post ){

     $keywords = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key2', true );
     echo '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $keywords . '" />';
}

add_action( 'wp_head',  'PrintKeywords' );
```

Comment: did you call `wp_head()` in header.php theme file

Comment: yes the echo is outputting

     <meta name="keywords" content="" />

Comment: use `global $post` and `print_r($post)`;

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure exactly what you mean, i tried replacing $post with global $post but that causes the code to break...

Comment: Ok i've just found one solution but if yo have any other please post!

the string stored in the variable is stored as an array

echo the array.

Comment: ohh nice, or try  `get_the_ID();` to get current post id instead `$post->ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place `global $post` in your function:

```
function PrintKeywords( $post ){
     global $post;
     $keywords = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key2', true );
     echo '<meta name="keywords" content="' . $keywords . '" />';
}
```